# Capture Mac media control keys in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome-extension

Two part question:

1. Is there a way to capture (react to the pressing of) the media playback control keys on a Mac keyboard (previous, play/pause, next) in a Google Chrome extension using strictly JavaScript?
2. `if (answerToQuestion1 === "no")` is there a way to do it using some sort of [native plugin](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi.html) (C/C++)?

I know that this should be possible, as [Unity Music Media Keys](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/icckhjgjjompfgoiidainoapgjepncej) does it (albeit I know that they're using a native plugin).

What I've looked at so far is [this plugin](https://github.com/borismus/Chrome-Media-Keys), which claims to do it, but actually requires [FunctionFlip](http://kevingessner.com/software/functionflip/) to make the keys act as function keys, and reacts to the pressing of <kbd>F7</kbd>, <kbd>F8</kbd>, and <kbd>F8</kbd>.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1 - nope =[

2 - Whoa - holy crap. I hadn't seen this extension before, so thank you for that. I dug into it a bit, and it seems that they install a .plugin on osx and a dll for windows support.

The decompiled plugin is only a couple hundred lines - https://gist.github.com/3849247.

They are using https://github.com/nevyn/SPMediaKeyTap as a way to plug in directly to the media keys (on os x). They are relaying that through a local socket.io server running on port 12345 to the browser, and the plugin is listening for events fired on it.

supppper neat.

EDIT:
This is now [natively supported in chrome](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+FrancoisBeaufort/posts/SDDSiLV5WVF)

Comment: +1 Thanks for the help. I will for sure be looking into these.

Answer (score 4):

Eventually I managed to accomplish what I was getting at. The final Chrome Extension can be see on [GitHub](https://github.com/whymarrh/media-keys).

How does it work?

The extension I originally linked to required that the function keys be "flipped" to actually be function keys and not have a special purpose, but doing so requires an extra keystroke to then perform the special functions (such as controlling keyboard backlights, volume, etc).

With great help from [Patrick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12771890/1267663), I used parts from [nevyn/SPMediaKeyTap](https://github.com/nevyn/SPMediaKeyTap) to capture the key presses outside the extension and [libwebsockets](http://libwebsockets.org/) to fire them over to the extension:

```
- (void) handleKeyCode: (int) kcode withKeyState: (int) kstate
{
    if (kstate) {
        return; // keydown
    }
    // keyup
    int len = 1;
    unsigned char data[LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING + len + LWS_SEND_BUFFER_POST_PADDING];
    data[LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING] = kcode;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_clients; i++) {
        libwebsocket_write(clients[i], &data[LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING], len, LWS_WRITE_TEXT);
        NSLog(@"Sent %d", kcode);
    }
}
```

Inside Chrome, the extension simply injects the appropriate piece of JS into the host page:

```
this.onmessage = function (message) {
    var keyCode = message.data.charCodeAt(0);
    if (keyCode === 20) {
        inject(function () {
            window.R.player.previous();
        });
    }
    if (keyCode === 16) {
        inject(function () {
            window.R.player.playPause();
        });
    }
    if (keyCode === 19) {
        inject(function () {
            window.R.player.next();
        });
    }
};
```